# How Displlay elements from API query , or put them in array

Tags: javascript, angular, edamam-api

Hello i want to display results from https://developer.edamam.com/edamam-docs-recipe-api this api or to put them into array

```
vm.search = function(){
  var req2 = {
      method: "GET",


    url:"https://api.edamam.com/search?q="+vm.searchText+"&app_id=myID&app_key=myKey"


  }
  $http(req2).then(
      function(resp){
        console.log(resp);
        vm.recepti = resp.data.Search;
        console.log(vm.recepti);


      }, function(resp){
          vm.message = 'error';
      });

};
```

i dont quite understand this particular api, or how do i display all recepies (names, images and other parameters that it has) from query result that users inputs in field with vm.searchText text box thanks for help in advance

*vm.recepti is an emtpy array* ,

[image]
when i go to query link i get this now how do i access properties based on this?

Comment: That is where debugging help. Check what `resp` actually is. Does it have any `data` property? Is this `data` property also an object? Does it have any `Search` property? keep asking questions and keep on debugging and you will find something meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do something like this:

vm.recepti = resp.data.hits;

Comment: thanks but i want only this part :
http://prntscr.com/hth7kk

when i try resp.data.hits.recipe; it wont work for some reason

Comment: That's why resp.data.hits is an array with N elements. So, if do you want only the first element, you can access it like : resp.data.hits[0].recipe. 

But if you want all the elements, you can use a for loop to loop over all the elements.

Something just like this:
resp.data.hits.forEach(function (item){ 
       console.log(item.recipe);
});
It will print all the recipes, from a array.